# How to right-click in google chrome

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, chrome-for-android, google-maps, mouse

I'm trying to get directions from two points on the map. I can't figure out how to do this in the mobile version of the site, so I switched to "classic" (desktop) mode. It says to right-click on the map to select a location. How do I right click? Long tap does not work. The stylus button does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several gestures which aren't really supported on mobile devices including right clicking, hovering and most keyboard shortcuts. It is up to website developers to recognize this when designing their user interfaces and either build in alternative gestures or simply rely on universal input methods like clicking/tapping.

Your best bet would be to contact the owner of the website you're having trouble with.

Comment: I'm sure Google will get right on that ;)

Comment: If you think about it, they already did.  They provided a native Maps app for the more involved interactions.

Comment: yeah except that it is missing a lot of functionality compared to the web page, which is why i wasn't using it to try to find directions between two points on the map.

Comment: Although it's unfortunate, there is no way to send a right click to a web page in a mobile browser using only the touchscreen.  Sites (like Maps) could choose to respond to alternative gestures like a long-hold, but are not required to.  Google chose to go the native app route for complicated interactions on mobile.  If this answers your question, please mark it as such.  If not, please do edit your question to describe what ur really after.